# showing umlauts in html with utf8 charset

Tags: html, utf-8

This question is most likely answered many times before, but I have searched some hours now and I still don't understand one basic thing (most probably the utf8-charset itself...).

I have a **html with german umlauts** "ä" and "ö" (`&auml;` and `&ouml;`):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
hällö
</body>
</html>
```

which results into the output of "h�ll�".

When I leave out `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` **the result becomes "hällö"** in my browser (probably with some german charset settings??) - as it should be.

**Why don't umlauts work like "normal" (ASCII) characters in utf8-charset
and what can I do to make them so (beside of encoding, decoding and masking)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specified "charset=utf-8", you have to upload/use a "File" that is encoded with UTF-8.

To do this on Windows:

1. Open your html/php.. file in Notepad.
2. go to "File" and choose "Save As"
3. Set the "Encoding" field to "UTF-8"

-> Profit

Answer (score 1):

> which results into the output of "h�ll�".

Those boxes are actually Unicode codepoint `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`, which means your HTML file is not actually encoded in UTF-8, as `ä` and `ö` are not valid UTF-8 byte octet sequences and are thus being replaced.

You need to either:

- make sure the file is actually saved in UTF-8 to begin with.
- change your declared `charset` to what it really is (most likely ISO-8859-1) (and make sure it also matches the `charset` attribute of the HTTP `Content-Type` header, if present).
- use HTML named entities instead of actual characters:

  ```
  h&auml;ll&ouml;
  ```

Comment: I think the first bullet is the thing I have done wrong. The other bullets are right too, but my current problem actually resulted from my wish to especially do not do those two ... Thank you very much :-)

Comment: *I think the first bullet is the thing I have done wrong* - that is usually the case.

Comment: actually I had to download a new editor as my (literally) old one seems not even capable of saving as utf8 - maybe that's at least a very humble explanation why I never stumbled upon this... so tradition seems a good thing only as long as you don't try something new.